# How to avoid SIGSEGV Errors on FPC compiler?

Tags: arrays, lazarus, freepascal, segmentation-fault

I'm currently having several problems with access violations in the program I'm building for my programming course. It is being build in pascal (the language used by the course) and using the Lazarus IDE (similar to Delphi but open).

As far as I know, Access Violations, or SIGSEGV errors, occurs when you try to use or address an invalid memory location. I've been trough a lot of these, specially when I wasn't declaring the length of dynamic arrays.

Now It seems I'm having this trouble with strings. (Or I might be derping with multi-dimensional arrays).

I'll paste only the procedure where the SIGSEGV is pointing, but the context is:

I have an array of integers and a multi-dimensional array containing it's power set **(subconjuntos)**, the function where the error is poping (described below) is used to print this power set to a TextBox(indexed by **local**):

```
procedure writeSub(local: TEdit);
var
  i, j: integer;
begin
 for i:= 0 to High(subconjuntos)+1 do
   if Length(subconjuntos[i])>1 then
   begin
     local.Text:=local.Text+'[';
     for j:=0 to High(subconjuntos[i])+1 do local.Text:=local.Text+'('+IntToStr(subconjuntos[i][j])+') ';
     local.Text:=local.Text+'] ';
   end
   else local.Text:=local.Text+'['+IntToStr(subconjuntos[i][0])+'] '; {this is where I'm having the SIGSEG, the program wont compile if I don't reference it without the double brackets}
end;
```

Any ideas why it is throwing SIGSEGV's?

Comment: I removed the Delphi tag, because this question isn't applicable to Delphi. Delphi does not throw SIGSEGVs, does not use FPC, and therefore has no relevance to this problem. It's also not appropriate to include tag information in your question title; the tag system works extremely well here to classify questions and get them to the people who are familiar with those tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamic arrays have valid indices in the range `low(arr)` to `high(arr)` inclusive. And `low(arr)` is always zero for a dynamic array. You attempt to access an element with index `high(arr)+1`. That is off the end of the array and is certainly a mistake.

Where you wrote

```
for i:= 0 to High(subconjuntos)+1 do
```

it should be

```
for i:= 0 to High(subconjuntos) do
```

or

```
for i:= Low(subconjuntos) to High(subconjuntos) do
```

and likewise for your other loop.

On top of that, `subconjuntos[i][0]` is an out of bounds access if `Length(subconjuntos[i])` is zero.

If you enable range checking in the compiler options then the compiler will emit code to check the validity of each array access. Doing this will lead you more quickly to such errors.

Comment: Thanks for the patience David. You got me to learn a lot. Now it is working. I used subconjuntos[i][low(subconjuntos[i])] and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Well, if `subconjuntos[i]` is `nil` then it has no elements, and so `subconjuntos[i][...]` will be an error whatever you put inside the inner array indices. So you do need to ensure that `subconjuntos[i]` is not `nil`. Also, a short-hand is to write `arr[i,j]` instead of `arr[i][j]`.

Comment: Didn't know that FPC accpeted arr[i,j] notation. Thanks for the new info.